# How to docker remove all containers based on image name

Tags: docker

My docker sometimes create randomw container name based on my docker image e.g. `yeeyi`

How to `docker rm` all off the containers where the image is `yeeyi`?

is there something like? `docker rm all --image yeeyi` in a single command line?

[image]

Answer (score 17):

You can do this using this command:

`docker rm $(docker ps -a -q --filter "ancestor=ubuntu")`

replace `ubuntu` with your image name. 
This basically gets all the container ids (running or otherwise) that use the image ubuntu and then removes them.

Comment: `docker ps -a -q --filter "ancestor=ubuntu"` does not return if I rebuild the image `ubuntu`

Comment: just a note, we could use first few word of `image_id` instead of `image_name`.

Comment: Alternatively, one can issue `docker ps -a -q --filter "name=yeeyi" | xargs docker container rm`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below workaround(update the grep string according to your need);

```
docker ps --filter "status=exited" | grep yeeyi
```

Check the output of above command, if you have the correct list, then use the below command;

```
docker rm (docker ps --filter "status=exited" | grep yeeyi | awk '{print $1}')
```

Another option is to check the exit code of such randomly created container. If that code is different then rest you can use the below command to get list of such containers;

```
docker ps -a --filter "exited=<status code>"
```